# Javascript replace matched group

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to build a text formatter that will add p and br tags to text based on line breaks. I currently have this:

```
s.replace(/\n\n/g, "\n</p><p>\n");
```

Which works wonderfully for creating paragraph ends and beginnings. However, trying to find 
 instances isn't working so well. Attempting to do a matched group replacement isn't working, as it ignores the parenthesis and replaces the entire regex match:

```
s.replace(/\w(\n)\w/g, "<br />\n");
```

I've tried removing the g option (still replaced entire match, but only on first match). Is there another way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can capture the parts you don't want to replace and include them in the replacement string with `$` followed by the group number:

```
s.replace(/(\w)\n(\w)/g, "$1<br />\n$2");
```

[See this section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter) in the MDN docs for more info on referring to parts of the input string in your replacement string.

Answer (score 3):

Catch the surrounding characters also:

```
s.replace(/(\w)(\n\w)/g, "$1<br />$2");
```